# Trouble With Regexp

Tags: php, regex

I have to replace matches of patterns like `<something:any-char>` within a `URL`.
For example, a `URL` like this:

```
http://some-site.com/some-acion/pippo:1/mypar:asdasd/pippo2:sdd/ .....
```

should become:

```
http://some-site.com/some-acion/pippo:1/pippo2:sdd/ .....
```

In other words, I have to filter out any occurrence of `mypar:` from the URL.
I will use php for that.
I tried with RegExp:

```
.*[\/]+(sh:.*)[\/]?.*$
```

But it matches only strings like `/pippo:3/mypar:wdfds`. Strings like `/pippo:2/mypar:asa/7pippo:1/` are not matched.
Any hint appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you know what you're doing. Why would you write `{1}` as a quantifier?

Comment: I know what I am doing, I just made a mistake. Thank you. Updated the question.

Comment: ok it was an example. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$url = "/pippo:2/mypar:asa/7pippo:1/";
$stripped = preg_replace("/\/mypar:.*?(\/|$)/", "$1", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the lazy dot matching `.*?` with a positive lookahead `(?=/|$)` (either a `/` or the end of string) can be replaced with a mere *any 0+ chars other than `/`* with `[^/]*`:

```
'~/mypar:[^/]*~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF9hZ0/1)

The `~` delimiter makes it possible to use `/` in the pattern without escaping.

**Pattern details:**

- `/` - a forward slash
- `mypar:` - a sequence of literal characters
- `[^/]*` - zero or more characters other than `/` character

See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/PhYPA1):

```
$re = '~/mypar:[^/]*~'; 
$str = "/pippo:2/mypar:asa/7pippo:1/";
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str, 1);
echo $result;
```